# React Rendering a collection correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react-firebase-hooks https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/v4.0.2/database#full-example

Below is values return when I console.log(v.val()) and when I do console.log(v.val().name) it's undefined.

```
{
  1: { id: 1, name: "bob", status: "student" }
  2: { id: 2, name: "sam", status: "student" }
}
```

When I try to render above data. I get the error Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children use an array instead.

```
import { ref, getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import { useList } from 'react-firebase-hooks/database';

const database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

const DatabaseList = () => {
  const [snapshots, loading, error] = useList(ref(database, 'list'));

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {error && <strong>Error: {error}</strong>}
        {loading && <span>List: Loading...</span>}
        {!loading && snapshots && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <span>
              List:{' '}
              {snapshots.map((v) => (
                <React.Fragment key={v.key}>{v.val()}, </React.Fragment>
              ))}
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I render my data correctly?

Comment: Can you console log snapshots? Is that a object or array? I am a bit confused here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `v.val()` is an object of objects, and as you are interested in the `name`, you need to get the values of the first object and then map through it and hence access the `name`.

```
import { ref, getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import { useList } from 'react-firebase-hooks/database';

const database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

const DatabaseList = () => {
  const [snapshots, loading, error] = useList(ref(database, 'list'));

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {error && <strong>Error: {error}</strong>}
        {loading && <span>List: Loading...</span>}
        {!loading && snapshots && (
            <span>
              List:{' '}
              {snapshots.map((v,i) => (
                Object.values(v.val()).map((obj,j) => 
                  <span key={i+j}>{obj.name}, </span>
                )
              ))}
            </span>
        )}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have a typo, you want `i + j` for key, but I'm not sure that's correct, it might cause clashes.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yes you are right, it was a typo and I have edited my answer. Thank you!